# How do I use the discord-buttons-plugin inside cogs?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I use discord-buttons-plugin to implement buttons in bot.
But after splitting it into cogs, I don't know where to put the ButtonsClient...
When I put it under __ init __, the decorator says `NameError: name 'buttons' is not defined`

Here is my code.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_buttons_plugin import *
from discord_slash import cog_ext, SlashCommand, SlashCommandOptionType, SlashContext

class Clean_Cog(commands.Cog, ButtonsClient):
    guild_ids = []
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.buttons = ButtonsClient(bot)
        print("[Cogs]CLEAN_COMMAND has just constructed.")

    def cog_unload(self):
        return super().cog_unload()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("[READY] CleanCommand on ready.")

    # there is slashcommand ...
    async def _kick(self, ctx):
        await buttons.send(
            components=[
                ActionRow([Button(label="yes", style=ButtonType().Success, custom_id="test", disabled=False)])
            ]
        )

    #The error comes out here
    @buttons.click
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1000)
```

This is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 606, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\V8\cogs\clean.py", line 16, in <module>
    class Clean_Cog(commands.Cog, ButtonsClient):
  File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\V8\cogs\clean.py", line 65, in Clean_Cog
    @buttons.click
NameError: name 'buttons' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\V8\main.py", line 75, in <module>
    bot = TestBot(command_prefix="z!", intents=intents,
  File "C:\Users\******\Desktop\V8\main.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.load_extension(cog)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 678, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 609, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.clean' raised an error: NameError: name 'buttons' is not defined
```

Comment: Consider using discord.py 2.X where buttons and slash commands are implemented instead of third party libraries like ``buttons-plugin`` and ``discord_slash``

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you have to use `self.buttons` instead of `buttons`

Comment: if you create `ButtonsClient` as object inside `Cog`  - like `self.buttons = ButtonsClient(bot)` then you don't need to use this class `ButtonsClient` to define class `Cog` - you can use `class Clean_Cog(commands.Cog):` without `ButtonsClient`

Comment: if you had working code before splitting it into cogs then you could also show it in question (not in comments)

Comment: @furas I added full of error mesage.

Comment: you define only `self.buttons` and you should use `@self.button` - but it would need to define functions inside ie. `__init__`. Or you have to register function using normal function instead of decorator - something like `self.buttons.register(self.test)` (but you have to search in documentation if it use `.register()`,`.add()` or any other name). OR simpler: define `ButtonsClient` outside class.